# I animated my spaceship but not all objects follow the same path. I don't want to join all the objects

Tags: animation

[image: I want the object circled to follow the same path as the rest of the ship.]

I want the object circled to follow the same path as the rest of the ship.

Comment: How about parenting all objects to a single object, which follows the path correctly? Then you wouldn't need to join them but can move all by movig the parent object.

Comment: Thanks so much! but when I parent it goes slower than the spaceship and falls behind and the wing goes of on its own.

Comment: Have you removed the curve constraint from the "child" objects?

Comment: How do you remove the curve constraint from the child objects in blender 2.8?

Comment: In the [constraints panel](https://easyblend.org/html/rigging/constraints/introduction.html). See [adding/removing](https://easyblend.org/html/rigging/constraints/interface/adding_removing.html).

Comment: My contrants panel is empty and I have parented the objects